# How to create a list view from a string variable which is from an SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite, listview

In my database code I am currently going through the ID column of my SQLite database. Now at the moment this is returning a string variable which is listing ALL entries when I put it is a textview for example. But I want to put that variable in some sort of listview (or similar) and for the user to be able to click that listview and bring up the rest of the information relating to that primary key. I have been doing research and have found tutorials to do this but they do not suite what I want to do and didn't exactly work for me. Here is the code below which is in the activity that I want to show the list view. Thanks.

```
public class View_Saved_Dates extends Activity {
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_saved_dates);       
    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    Database info = new Database(this);
    info.open();
    //I want to put the variable below which lists all data within the id column of my database into a list view or some sort of list where I can 
    //click the id and bring up the rest of the information in the databse.
    String cowid = info.getCowid();

    info.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com.au/2011/06/simple-example-using-androids-sqlite_02.html) but have had no luck at all. My app just quits. I am pretty sure I followed the tutorial the right way.

Comment: If the app "just quits", that sounds like an uncaught exception to me. Check your error logs for stacktraces, or run your app in debug mode in an IDE such as Eclipse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Populating a list view from SQLite Database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621800/populating-a-list-view-from-sqlite-database)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below links-

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html

http://androidtuts4u.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-sqlite-and-listview-example.html

[How to Read Data from SQLite Database and show it on a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939187/how-to-read-data-from-sqlite-database-and-show-it-on-a-list-view)

[Display data from SQLite database into ListView in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15363411/display-data-from-sqlite-database-into-listview-in-android)

[How to get data form SQLite database and display it in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552983/how-to-get-data-form-sqlite-database-and-display-it-in-listview)

[how to fetch the data from sqlite database and show in listview in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548501/how-to-fetch-the-data-from-sqlite-database-and-show-in-listview-in-android)

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I beleive that this should fix your problem. In your database class, instead of putting all your queried data into a string put it into a string array.

```
public String[] getid() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] id = new String[]{KEY_ID};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, id, null, null, null, null, null);
    int i = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID);
    while(c.moveToNext()){ strings.add(c.getString(i));
    }
    String[] mString = (String[]) strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
    return mString;

}
```

Then in your main class where you want this list view to be displayed create a list view and use the following code and it should work

```
lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_view); 
    Database info = new Database(this);
    info.open();
    String [] id = info.getid();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, id);
    lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    info.close();
```

I hope that works for you